# Battery design capacity is zero?

Tags: battery

I've a Lenovo G780 unit for which the battery design capacity is reported as zero. 
This is a brand new unit.

In `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` I can find the following information:

- POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
- POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
- POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
- POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Unknown
- POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=1491
- POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=1000
- POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=11820000
- POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=635500000
- **POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=0**
- POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=47520000
- POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=36350000
- POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=
- POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Li-Ion
- POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=PABAS0241231

At first, I thought that this was a battery issue, but when I use Windows based battery tools, I get good values for the 3 capacity values:

- design capacity
- last full charged capacity
- current capacity

These 3 values are different in windows, so it's not that one of the capacity values is reused for one of the other values.

Any idea what the problem can be? Is this a Ubuntu defect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The information you get from the /sys interface is what the kernel is getting back from the ACPI battery information from _BIF or _BIX.  The _BIF and _BIX objects are normally populated from information from the smart battery which itself is usually gathered over some kind of i2c interface to an Embedded Controller (EC) and the ACPI controls get the data from the EC.   So the issue may be in the underlying firmware or ACPI controls.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

How can I narrow down this issue to find the source of the problem (firmware or ACPI)? Will this end up being a low level issue that must be solved in the BIOS or Linux kernel?

Comment: The kernel only reports what the battery is telling it.  Since the value is nonsense it could be checked for and worked around in the kernel.

Comment: BTW, we're looking at getting a workaround for this..

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1133328