# UPower reports Incorrect Capacity

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, acpi

I've just replaced my old Netbook battery with a new one of higher capacity.  It was a cheap battery off of Amazon which clearly reads as a 5200mAh battery but Ubuntu reports the battery as being the standard 4400mAh battery that came with the system and that it has 99% of its capacity left.

This seems very strange but I have no idea how to directly confirm the capacity.  I've installed acpi and run:

```
acpi -v
```

The returns the same information as UPower interface.  I've run:

```
sudo fwts battery
```

And the system reports the battery is fine for a new battery, though it does report a lack of ACPI events.

Is there any way to manually set the capacity (I have to do this with my Android phone and the battery monitoring app I use) or force it so rescan the battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be related to the problem that the manufacturer of the battery often does **not disclose the specification** of the battery, and for supplying a compatible - or at least **almost compatible** - battery, it's hard to build a correct 'battery chip'.
I think it could well be that the battery has about 5200mWh electrical capacity, but the chip does not know it, because it was easier to find or build a chip reporting 4400mAh.
That would mean, it reports no more than 4400mAh no matter what you do, but gives you more, and the battery capacity estimation will have to cope with the **inconsistent data** somehow.

---

There may be interesting info if you take a look at what you find in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` or so - see
 [Battery design capacity is zero?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261030/battery-design-capacity-is-zero). Maybe add it to the question if it looks interesting.

Comment: Do you perhaps know of a way to override what is reported?

Comment: If the problem really is what I describe, I do not think there is a general way to override it - what the battery says is assumed to be true, that's it. (But maybe you can find a way/a hack to override in some specific context.)

Comment: Well, I appreciate your help.  I am not as concerned with the reported numbers as making sure I get as good battery life as I can.  This first test of the system looks as if I'm going to average between 6 and 7 hours of life.  That is good for me, so as long as I get that I'm not going to worry about the details.  I contacted the vendor for my battery who says it is only supposed to be 4800 mAh and I know manufacturing usually leaves a mAh buffer to extend the life of a battery as it degrades in performance, so I will accept that.